# Form.Show() and Form.Visible ThreadSafe

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety

Ok..my main form consists of some user controls and some buttons that will open other forms.  I have a Background worker where the UI won't freeze up.  The background worker updates a clock on the form and also is checking a database for a certain condition to be met.  If the condition is met, this form is hidden and the new form is displayed.

I am also doing a check to see if the second form is already open.  Because once I open it, I don't close it.  I just use hide and show.  So my problem is, I can't find a thread-safe way to create and open a form, or to show the form if it is already open.  I also have to Hide the current form.

Here is the code I have

```
//bool variable to determine if i need to open the form
if (inShift)
            {
                frmInShift InShift = null;
                if ((InShift = (frmInShift)IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(frmInShift))) == null)
                {
                    InShift = new frmInShift();
                    InShift.RefToParent = this;
                }
                else
                {
                    InShift.RefToParent = this;
                }
                InShift.ResetButtons();
                InShift.Show();
                this.Visible = false;
            }
```

I know this code works, I am using it on one of the buttons on the form. I just need to make this thread-safe.  Part of the problem is actually creating the form if it isn't already open.

Should I do that check on the main thread? If that works, How will I call the Show() method?

EDIT:
I'm creating my second form on my main form load event.  So all I need to do is set a few public variables and show the form and hide the main form.

My RunWorkerCompleted code looks like this:

```
            if (inShift)
            {                   
                InShift.RefToParent = this;
                InShift.ResetButtons();
                InShift.Show();
                //program freezes up here
                this.Invoke(new ThisFormVisibleCB(ThisFormVisible), new object[] { false });
            }
```

The program freezes when I call Invoke on this to hide the form..help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved..stupid problem I should have caught a long time ago.

For starters..I got rid of the backgroundworker and put everything in a timer..it still didn't work.  Then I realized I was still using a "threading" timer.

I switched my timer from a

```
System.Timers.Timer
```

to a

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer
```

and it works perfectly now.